# Bootstrap with separate js File

Tags: jquery, javascript, wp-enqueue-script, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap for a few things in my Plugin. Now i want to move the needed js to an externeal file. But if i do this it stops working. I already searched a while but i can´t get it to work.

I added everything to WordPress

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'ecp_admin_jquery', plugins_url('/ext/jquery-3.1.1.min.js' , __FILE__), array(), '3.1.1', false );
wp_enqueue_script( 'ecp_admin_bootstrap', plugins_url('/ext/bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js' , __FILE__), array(), '3.3.7', false );
wp_enqueue_script( 'ecp_admin_js', plugins_url('/js/script.js' , __FILE__), array(), '1.0', false );
```

Now i have the following example

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">Tooltip on top</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom">Tooltip on bottom</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">Tooltip on right</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
});
</script>
```

Works perfect. But when i move the

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
});
```

to my script.js file it´s not working anymore. Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'ecp_admin_js', plugins_url('/js/script.js' , __FILE__), array(), '1.0', false );
```

Has to be:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'ecp_admin_js', plugins_url('/js/script.js' , __FILE__), array(), '1.0', true );
```

Only if set to true the Script is added to the Footer (above closing body-Tag)!